# how to use vanilla-extract for `style` attribute?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, css-in-js, vanilla-extract

Have a following sample of code which I want migrate to vanilla-extract, my main question is how to generate styles for `style` attribute in this case?

```
// in ColorToken.tsx

function ColorToken(props: { name: string; value?: string }) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundColor: `var(${props.value})`,
        border: 'solid 1px var(--color-border-neutral)',
        borderRadius: '100%',
        width: '70px',
        height: '70px',
      }}
    >
      {props.name}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried two approaches:

#### First

```
// ColorToken.css.ts

import { style } from '@vanilla-extract/css';

export function colorSelector(bgColor: string) {
  return style({
    backgroundColor: bgColor,
    border: 'solid 1px var(--color-border-neutral)',
    borderRadius: '100%',
    width: '70px',
    height: '70px',
  });
}
```

```
// ColorToken.tsx

import * as selectors from './Colors.css';

function ColorToken(props: { name: string; value?: string }) {
  const color: string = // dynamically piking color based on props.
  return (
    <div className={selectors.colorSelector(color)}>
```

Error / issue:

```
error - ./pages/styles/tokens/Colors.css.ts
Error: Invalid exports.

You can only export plain objects, arrays, strings, numbers and null/undefined.
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

---

#### Second

```
// ColorToken.css.ts

export const colorSelector = {
  border: 'solid 1px var(--color-border-neutral)',
  borderRadius: '100%',
  width: '70px',
  height: '70px',
};
```

```
// ColorToken.tsx

import { style } from '@vanilla-extract/css';

import * as selectors from './Colors.css';

function ColorToken(props: { name: string; value?: string }) {
  const color: string = // dynamically piking color based on props.
  return (
    <div className={style({ ...selectors.colorSelector, backgroundColor: color })}>
```

Note: here I'm using `style` function because I think VE might apply some extra things (e.g add vendor prefixes, optimizations etc).

Error / issue:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Styles were unable to be assigned to a file. This is generally caused by one of the following:

- You may have created styles outside of a '.css.ts' context
- You may have incorrect configuration. See https://vanilla-extract.style/documentation/setup
```

---

Note: using [VE via NextJS setup](https://vanilla-extract.style/documentation/setup/#nextjs).

Answer (score 2):

The key to keep in mind here is that vanilla works at build time. It outputs a plain CSS stylesheet, so trying to substitute values in at runtime isn't what it's built for.

If you have a clearly defined set of background colours that you want to use, you could use a [recipe](https://vanilla-extract.style/documentation/packages/recipes/), or you could start to build up some atomic CSS with [sprinkles](https://vanilla-extract.style/documentation/packages/sprinkles/).

If it needs to be truly dynamic, impossible to know at build time, you can take advantage of CSS variables using vanilla's [dynamic](https://vanilla-extract.style/documentation/packages/dynamic/) package.